# mapping a keras model over a list of tibbles

Tags: r, keras

I have the below code which uses the `iris` data set to train a number of Machine Learning models:

I want to make predictions for the `keras` model. The below code works and I am able to obtain predictions for all the models (except the `keras` model):

When I uncomment the `else if` - `keras` part of the code I obtain "errors" or the model produces.

```
[1] "skipping\n"
[1] "skipping\n"
[1] "skipping\n"
[1] "skipping\n"
[1] "skipping\n"
[1] "skipping\n"
[1] "skipping\n"
[1] "skipping\n"
[1] "skipping\n"
[1] "skipping\n"
[1] "skipping\n"
[1] "skipping\n"
```

My question is where am I going wrong on the `keras` predict part? I want to modify this part of the code such that it will give me predicted classes:

```
  # else if(attr(x, "class")[1] == "keras_training_history"){
  #   # Keras Single Layer Neural Network
  #   tibble(
  #     modelname = attr(x, "class")[1],
  #     prediction = predict_classes(object = x, x = as.matrix(dat))
  #   )
  # }
```

EDIT 1:

My attempt at the debugging:

```
dat <- iris %>% 
  filter(Species != "setosa") %>% 
  mutate(Species = +(Species == "virginica"))

mod <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 2, activation = 'relu', input_shape = 2) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 2, activation = 'softmax')
mod
mod %>% compile(
    loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer_sgd(lr = 0.01, momentum = 0.9),
    metrics = c('accuracy')
  ) 
mod
fit(mod, 
    x = as.matrix(dat[, 2:3]),
    y = to_categorical(dat$Species, 2),
    epochs = 5,
    batch_size = 5,
    validation_split = 0
  )

predict_classes(mod, as.matrix(dat[, 2:3]))
```

Gives me:

```
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [44] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [87] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

EDIT:

When I run the code in EDIT 1. and then pass:

```
attr(mod, "class")
```

I get the following output:

```
[1] "keras.engine.sequential.Sequential"                        
[2] "keras.engine.training.Model"                               
[3] "keras.engine.network.Network"                              
[4] "keras.engine.base_layer.Layer"                             
[5] "tensorflow.python.module.module.Module"                    
[6] "tensorflow.python.training.tracking.tracking.AutoTrackable"
[7] "tensorflow.python.training.tracking.base.Trackable"        
[8] "python.builtin.object"
```

However when I run the `models_list` code and then run the following:

```
attr(models_list[[1]]$models$Model_Keras, "class")
```

I get:

```
[1] "keras_training_history"
```

So I am passing a different function to the `predict`. Therefore I am starting to think the code when building the model stores the data incorrectly.

Comment: It may be easier to debug, if you build the same model kerass alone and then use the `predict``

Comment: I did that also. I add the code to the edit.

Comment: Just trying it.  Taking some time.  For me, the example gives all 1s

Comment: In the loop code you are passing the whole dataset instead of subset of columns.  Does it have any issues `prediction = predict_classes(object = x, x = as.matrix(dat))`

Comment: I tried `predict_classes(models_list[[1]]$models$Model_Keras, x = boundary_lists[[1]])#
Error in do.call(object$predict_classes, args) : 
  'what' must be a function or character string`

Comment: I think there is a difference in the structure of `mod` and `models_list[[1]]$models$Model_Keras` because the first one is `fit`

Comment: I was getting that error also at some times. I added an EDIT 2, to the data about the model classes being passed to the predict function. Perhaps this might be the cause.

Comment: Yes, it is only `attr(models_list[[1]]$models$Model_Keras, "class")#
[1] "keras_training_history"` because in the `mods`, it adds the attributes after the `fit`

Comment: Is it possible to train a `keras` model in one single `pipe` function? or are parts of it needed to be stored separately.

Comment: I was trying to do this in the `map2`, but the 'dat' comes from the `boundary_lists` doesn't have the 'Speciess' column

Comment: I think you need to remove the `%>%` for the `fit`

Comment: The `boundary_lists` doesn't have the `Species` column since it is "synthetically" created as a testing dataset so it will only make class predictions on this data.

Comment: I got it.  I am checking in the model_list

Comment: I think the object needs to be `assign`ed in the global env.  For e.g. `out1 <- vector('list', 2);
lst1 <- list(dat, dat);

nm1 <- paste0("mod", 1:2)` and then looping `for(i in seq_along(lst1)) { ..., assign(nm1[i], mod)}` and check `mod1` `mod2`. If you do the. assignment to an object i.e. `out1[[i]] <- fit(mod, ..` it is only capturing the attributess of the last part and thus having an issue

Comment: `attr(mod1, "class")#
[1] "keras.engine.sequential.Sequential"                        
[2] "keras.engine.training.Model"                               
[3] "keras.engine.network.Network"                              
[4] "keras.engine.base_layer.Layer"                             
[5] "tensorflow.python.module.module.Module"                    
[6] "tensorflow.python.training.tracking.tracking.AutoTrackable"
[7] "tensorflow.python.training.tracking.base.Trackable"        
[8] "python.builtin.object"` and similarly for `mod2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an issue of not capturing all the attributes.  If we do an `assign`ment, it would work.  Below, show a single case by using only the keras model (Make changes by wrapping with the `if/else`)

```
models_list <- var_combos %>%
                    mutate(modeln = str_c('mod', row_number()))  %>%
                    pmap(~ 
                          {

                           xname = ..1
                           yname = ..2
                           modelname = ..3
                           df %>%
                              select(Species, xname, yname) %>%
                               group_by(grp = 'grp') %>%
                               nest() %>%
                               mutate(models = map(data, ~{


                                list(Model_Keras = {
                                mod <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
                                  layer_dense(units = 2, activation = 'relu', input_shape = 2) %>% 
                                  layer_dense(units = 2, activation = 'softmax')

                                mod %>% compile(
                                    loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
                                    optimizer_sgd(lr = 0.01, momentum = 0.9),
                                    metrics = c('accuracy')
                                  )


                                  fit(mod, 
                                      x = as.matrix(.x[, 2:3]),
                                      y = to_categorical(.x$Species, 2),
                                      epochs = 5,
                                      batch_size = 5,
                                      validation_split = 0
                                    )
                                print(modelname)        
                                assign(modelname, mod)                      

                                }   )                      

                                   }                               
                               ))                 

                              })
```

Now, apply this on the `predict_classes`

```
models_predict <- map2(models_list, boundary_lists, ~{
     mods <- purrr::pluck(.x, "models")
      dat <- .y
      map(mods, function(x) 
        predict_classes(object = x$Model_Keras, x = as.matrix(dat)))

  })
```

-output

```
head(models_predict[[5]][[1]])
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
head(models_predict[[7]][[1]])
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks again! I will try to work this into the current code/if else statements.